# Jboss is changing the file permission of a directory under the deployed war

Tags: java, jboss7.x, apache-commons

I have code in my j2ee web applicaiton directory which deletes the contents of a sub directory under the deployed War and then replaces with the new ones.

The code works fine in Tomcat but fails in Jboss. This happens in Windows 7 but not in Ubuntu . In Ubuntu , I installed JBoss under user home directory.

I am using the ApacheIO's FileUtils.cleanDirectory method to clean the contents of the subdirectory.

In another test , I wrote a simple Test class with the following lines

```
  File file = new File("D:\\appserver\\jboss-eap-
 7.0\\standalone\\deployments\\MyWar.war\\common\\graphpane2");
 File jsFile = new File(file, "js");
 System.out.println("jsFile.isDirectory() = " + jsFile.isDirectory());
 System.out.println("jsFile.isDirectory() = " + jsFile.exists());
 System.out.println("file = " + file.exists());
 //File file = new File("D:\\VMs\\tex.txt");
 try {
   FileUtils.cleanDirectory(file);
 } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

When jboss is running , jsFile.exists() is returning false inspite of the fact that the directory exists. But when jboss is closed, code just works fine.

Another point - When I go the the directory manually through windows explorer and delete the subdirectory, I get a windows dialog saying that I need permission from the user.

I ran the Jboss through a command prompt opening the command prompt itself as an administrator. But no help.

Needless say any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. I am using JBoss 7.0 eap.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do?  You should **never** be writing directly to the files in your web application.  JBoss (and others) can move things around during deployment and runtime and don't need to document where things physically live.

Comment: Well I am writing to files inside my web application. Will change it but for current code support, I need to get a fix. So to retierate, there is a 'comm' directory which basically contains .js files as well as images......in the admin console of my web app, I get a utility to update the comm directory with new files. For that I am clearing the <WAR_DIR>/comm directory and updating it with new one.   Thanks